# iOS integration/acceptance/functional testing for standalone modules/frameworks

Tags: ios, swift, integration-testing, functional-testing, acceptance-testing

I'm currently looking at various integration/functional/acceptance testing frameworks for iOS and they all seem to rely heavily on the UI and accessibility labels. To me a lot of these seem more based towards UI tests as opposed to integration testing. Are there any dedicated frameworks that don't rely on this, especially when working with modules/frameworks that aren't built with a UI?

Is XCTest the way to go here when testing this kind of functionality? I've seen fitnesse and this seems to be the only other option I've found so far.

So in this instance I could have something like an API framework that is purely responsible for making network requests, parsing the response and creating relevant objects. Whilst I would write unit tests to test the individual pieces of functionality, I would also like to test an end to end flow.

Are there any suitable testing frameworks for this type of thing? Preferably swift based

thanks